# Primers on Dystonia

Tags: genetics, biochemistry, mice, research-process

Where can I get a good biochemical overview of dystonia? I will be working in a research lab that focuses on dystonia and I would like to not be clueless.

Answer (score 2):

A good article on the pathophsiology is,

The pathophysiological basis of dystonias, Nature Reviews Neuroscience 9, 222-234 (March 2008)

For a review of the treatment,

Treatment of dystonia, lancet neurology, Volume 5, Issue 10, October 2006, Pages 864–872.

A comprehensive textbook on movement disorders in general is The oxford textbook of movement disorders

Comment: this is a bit fragmented and hard to read - can you spruce it up a bit?